Calling an existing C# dll from VB.net
I am trying to control a FT601 USB3 interface chip via a C# wrapper that FTDI provide. Unfortunately, they don't provide an example of using VB.net to do this, but advise that it should be possible. I have written a simple test program to see if this works and it appears to have no errors, but running the call results in a 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException', despite having referenced the dll in the project. It seems that I may not be calling the dll correctly, but I haven't spotted the problem.
Module Module1
    Public Sub FTDread()
        'Find & Open all FTDI devices attached
        Dim ftStatus As FTDI.FT_STATUS = FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK
        Dim d3xxDevice As New FTDI()
        Dim ulNumDevices As UInt32
        ftStatus = d3xxDevice.GetNumberOfDevicesConnected(ulNumDevices)
        If ftStatus <> FTDI.FT_STATUS.FT_OK OrElse ulNumDevices = 0 Then
            Return
        End If
        MsgBox(ulNumDevices)
    End Sub
End Module

Here is the error as shown in VB.net

Exception thrown: 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' in StarMos.dll An
exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in
StarMos.dll but was not handled in user code Could not load file or
assembly 'FTD3XX_NET, Version=1.3.0.10, Culture=neutral,
PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
'StarMos.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft
Visual
Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies\Runtime\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.NetCoreApp.dll'.
Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
'Just My Code' is enabled. 'StarMos.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded
'C:\Program
Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\7.0.15\netstandard.dll'.
Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
'Just My Code' is enabled. The program '[29168] StarMos.exe' has
exited with code 4294967295 (0xffffffff).


Post the entire stack trace of your error message.

If the C# dll is a "wrapper", there's probably another dll that it wraps.  You need that in your /bin folder too.

Depending on your build process, you may want to make some changes to your project to automatically deliver the wrapped dll on build.

This isn't about C# at all. All .NET DLLs are the same as far as a project is concerned. FTDI is a hardware manufacturer, which means the C# wrapper is wrapping a native DLL provided by FTDI itself. A wrapper written in VB.NET or C# is useless without that library

Did I mention that you need to provide a complete error message in your post?

I checked my "older" FTDI implementation (FTD2), and besides a dll, there was an xml file (which sounds more like a "file not found"). It had a lot of "FTD2->NET" related info. That said, you should check the contents of your bin folders. (debug/release)

Many thanks for the input everyone. Unfortunately, I still haven't fixed the problem, despite making sure that both dlls are in the bin folders etc. It's proving to be a difficult one to solve!

Based on FTDI's website code examples, you should have two dlls in your project:
a) FTD3XX.dll       (base DLL)
b) FTD3XX_NET.dll   (wrapper)
